# The dataframe values used to create the geotiff, and the values extracted from geotiff are not matching

Tags: python, raster, geopandas, rasterio

I have created a geotiff file using the code below.
#part1: code for geotiff creation.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import rasterio as rio

# Define the range of latitudes and longitudes
lat_range = (39, 41)
lon_range = (-76, -73)

# Define the resolution of the grid
resolution = 0.1

# Create arrays of the latitude and longitude values
lats = np.arange(lat_range[0], lat_range[1], resolution)
lons = np.arange(lon_range[0], lon_range[1], resolution)

# Create a meshgrid of the latitude and longitude values
lon_mesh, lat_mesh = np.meshgrid(lons, lats)

# Flatten the meshgrids into 1D arrays of latitude and longitude values
lat_values = lat_mesh.flatten()
lon_values = lon_mesh.flatten()

# Generate random z values for each latitude and longitude pair
z_values = np.random.rand(len(lat_values))

# Create a pandas DataFrame to store the data
data = pd.DataFrame({'lat': lat_values, 'lon': lon_values, 'z': z_values})

# Define the GeoTIFF file parameters
width = len(lons)
height = len(lats)
transform = rio.transform.from_bounds(lon_range[0], lat_range[0], lon_range[1], lat_range[1], width, height)
crs = rio.crs.CRS.from_epsg(4326)  # WGS 1984

# Write the GeoTIFF file
with rio.open("output.tif", "w", driver="GTiff", width=width, height=height, count=1, dtype=np.float32, nodata=0, transform=transform, crs=crs) as dst:
    # Reshape the z values into a 2D array and write them to the GeoTIFF file
    z_array = z_values.reshape((height, width))
    dst.write(z_array, 1)
```

Then used the following code to extract the values from the above geotiff file stored as output.tif
#part2: code for extraction.

```
import rasterio as rio
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np

# Load the GeoTIFF file
with rio.open(r"E:\\Machine_Learning_for_Himalaya_IEEE_GRSL\\plots\\output.tif") as src:
    # Extract the metadata for the file
    meta = src.meta
    print("meta:",meta)
    # Define the latitude and longitude ranges
    lat_range = (39, 41)
    lon_range = (-76, -73)

    # Create a grid of points with a 0.1 degree interval within the specified ranges
    lats = np.arange(lat_range[0], lat_range[1], 0.1)
    lons = np.arange(lon_range[0], lon_range[1], 0.1)
    lon_mesh, lat_mesh = np.meshgrid(lons, lats)
    geometry = gpd.points_from_xy(lon_mesh.ravel(), lat_mesh.ravel())
    points = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=geometry)

    # Extract the z values at the point locations using rasterio.sample
    zs = list(src.sample(zip(points.geometry.x, points.geometry.y)))

    # Create a Pandas DataFrame to store the point coordinates and values
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Latitude': lat_mesh.ravel(),
                       'Longitude': lon_mesh.ravel(),
                       'Value': zs})

print(df)
```

The outputs are as follows:
for second part following is output:

```
meta: {'driver': 'GTiff', 'dtype': 'float32', 'nodata': 0.0, 'width': 30, 'height': 20, 'count': 1, 'crs': CRS.from_epsg(4326), 'transform': Affine(0.1, 0.0, -76.0,
       0.0, -0.1, 41.0)}
     Latitude  Longitude        Value
0        39.0      -76.0        [0.0]
1        39.0      -75.9        [0.0]
2        39.0      -75.8        [0.0]
3        39.0      -75.7        [0.0]
4        39.0      -75.6        [0.0]
..        ...        ...          ...
595      40.9      -73.5  [0.5188609]
596      40.9      -73.4   [0.589194]
597      40.9      -73.3  [0.5691334]
598      40.9      -73.2  [0.8172998]
599      40.9      -73.1  [0.5687353]

[600 rows x 3 columns]
```

if we print the dataframe i.e., data from the part1 code the output is as below.

```
      lat   lon         z
0    39.0 -76.0  0.613836
1    39.0 -75.9  0.002668
2    39.0 -75.8  0.432013
3    39.0 -75.7  0.912882
4    39.0 -75.6  0.892871
..    ...   ...       ...
595  40.9 -73.5  0.170039
596  40.9 -73.4  0.340669
597  40.9 -73.3  0.809385
598  40.9 -73.2  0.501880
599  40.9 -73.1  0.085377

[600 rows x 3 columns]
```

we can clearly see the values are different for same coordinates in the above outputs. How to sort this and why this is happening. can some one help me understand this.

Comment: On your `part2`, you extract `meta = src.meta`, but you never use it.

Comment: That's correct. I am extracting it to ensure whether the raster is getting created as per the information i.e., coordinates I gave or not.

Answer (score 0):

I also reguarly get confused by this type of problem.

In the create part you should flip the input array so:

```
z_array = z_values.reshape((height, width))[::-1]
```

Then it will work correctly.

You should also consider shifting the transform 0.5 resolution like this:

```
transform = rio.transform.from_bounds(lon_range[0]-0.5*resolution, lat_range[0]-0.5*resolution, lon_range[1]-0.5*resolution, lat_range[1]-0.5*resolution, width, height)
```

then the cell middles instead of edges are in the ranges you provide.

Answer (score 0):

The first part of your code is nice.

Whereas the second part could be simplified a lot like [it was explained here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/365538/exporting-geotiff-raster-to-geopandas-dataframe)

In your case it yields:

```
import rioxarray as xr

dataarray = xr.open_rasterio("output.tif")
df = dataarray[0].to_pandas()
print(df.head())
dataarray.close()
```

This cell output will look this way:

[image]

and it is exactly the same as `z_array` from the first part of your code.

In general, I would say that the problem comes from using DataFrames which aren't very natural for the geospatial data. When you are creating `data`, all the values go there in the order you say. But when you are writing GTiff, values are arranged according to their coordinates. In your case bigger latitude is on the top of raster (first rows of your `z_array` go there so to say).